# "Oblong to Allantoids" .... Is it valid?

Tags: microbiology

I read on the text book:

The characteristic of *Dinemasporium* are: superficial, cupulate to *Discoid conidiomata* with brown satae, *Phialid conidiogenous* cells that give rise to hyaline, **oblong to *Allantoids***, and *Aseptate conidia* with an appendage at each end.

My question:

the phrase "oblong to *Allantoids*"; Is the word **oblong** valid for this context? if not, what other word would associate?

Answer (score 1):

Oblong is probably correct in this context, but "allantoids" should probably be "allantoid" to be the adjective form. It's describing translucent (hyaline), oval (oblong) to sausage-shaped (allantoid), undivided (aseptate) spore.

Comment: Thank you, I should have referred to [this link](http://www.persoonia.org/Issue/28/10.pdf).